# Why is it the case that $m\geq n$, we have that $\bigcap_{k = n}^\infty A_k \subseteq A_m$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I read in a book that for $m\geq n$, we have that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{k = n}^\infty A_k \subseteq A_m$.

I've tried everything to understand this intuitively but cannot grasp it. It appears to me that the intersection can be thought of as keeping a common item between each of the sets, but that doesn't seem to make it a subset of any individual item. Would anyone have any insights?

Comment: Based on this and a few other questions you've asked recently it seems like you need to go back and learn what $\cap$, $\cup$ and $\subset$ mean. They don't mean the fuzzy things you've been saying it seems like they mean - they have precise simple definitions.

Comment: This is basically a generalization of the fact that $A\cap B\subseteq B$, which you can convince yourself of with a Venn diagram. (Similarly, $A\cap B\cap C\subseteq C$, which you can also convince yourself of with a Venn diagram.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in \cap_{k=n}^\infty A_k$ so $x\in A_k$ for all $k\ge n$ so in particular $x\in A_m$ since $m\ge n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k$.  Now if $x\in A$, then $x\in A_m$ for all $m\ge n$ by the definition of intersection.  Hence $A\subseteq A_m$.

Answer (score 0):

For $m\ge n$ the set $A_m$ participates in the intersection $\bigcap _{k\ge n}A_k$. So, the claim follows from the more general claim that if $B_i$ are a bunch of sets indexed by some set $I$, then $A_{i_0}$ is contained in the intersection $\bigcap _{i\in I}A_i$, for each $i_0\in I$. Do you see why that latter claim is true?